# Stop server core 2016 prompting to install Silverlight?

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-server-core

I have a server 2016 core set up as one domain controller, there's a second DC which is a full server 2016 with GUI.

Almost every time I log on to the 2016 core machine, it prompts about available updates it wants to install, and it's always "Microsoft Silverlight (KB4023307)".

I located that update through powershell some time ago, and changed its state to hidden.
It's still hidden when I check it today:
(Not my own script, stolen from a page on GitHubGist and edited to show hidden updates instead of regular ones)

```
$UpdateSession = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session
$UpdateSearcher = $UpdateSession.CreateupdateSearcher()
$Updates = @($UpdateSearcher.Search("IsHidden=1 and IsInstalled=0").Updates)
$Updates | Select-Object Title
```

Result:

```
Title
-----
Microsoft Silverlight (KB4023307)
```

Yet the only reason why I just ran that piece of script is that I *again* got prompted to install updates.
Started sconfig, chose option 6, 'a', and I was rewarded with this (empty lines deleted):

```
Searching for all applicable updates...
List of applicable items on the machine:
1> Microsoft Silverlight (KB4023307)
```

Does anyone know a way to get rid of it and never hear from it again?

Letting it install it doesn't help, it fails, and it beats me why you would want to have it on a core machine anyway.

Comment: Do you already have Silverlight installed? That KB refers to a security update for it.

Comment: I don;t even know, is Silverlight still installed as a windows feature on 2016? It is listed as neither installed nor available by Get-WindowsFeature | where { $_.Name -like '*si*' }

Comment: Found a wmic command to check for it: it says "No Instance(s) available", so I assume not installed. The same command on my windows 10 machine returns "Microsoft Silverlight", so that works.